Can I double dip free lounge passes to get 2 guests in?
I have two credit cards that offer a few free airport lounge visits per year: one via Priority Pass, the other via DragonPass.  Quite a few lounges are signed up to both programs.
Here's the issue: I often travel with family, meaning there's 4 of us.  However, the T&C of both programs is quite clear that the passes can only be used by the primary cardholder (me) and exactly 1 accompanying guest, meaning I need to pay the full price for the other 2.
Can I "double dip" to bring in guest 1 with card 1 plus guest 2 with card 2, and thus pay only for guest 3?  (And yes, this would use up 2 entries per card = 4 entries, but since they're free anyway, it doesn't really matter.)

What stops you from going in with a guest, leaving the lounge immediately (leave your first guest inside) and come back in with another 2 guests?

that seems to be the question here, André

@André These days lounges scan boarding passes on entry, so there's a non-zero chance the scanner goes "boop" if I'm in already. Plus there's a human at the gate doing the scanning who will notice shenanigans.  But I'm not trying to haxx0r the system here, just use my benefits.

This will depend a bit on your negotiating skills and the mood of the lounge dragon.
You can always ask to bring your partner as a guest and the children for free. Some lounges will allow this, especially if the kids are younger and cute.
Failing that, you can try to enter twice, bringing one guest each time. Lounges scan boarding passes, so they will typically know that you are double dipping. However, that's not necessarily a problem. This way the (contract) lounge gets paid twice for the same patron. They have no particular reason to refuse this even if they can. I also don't see any problem with asking up front how they want to handle this.
This way you can get you plus two guests in the lounge but if you want to get 4 people in, all you can do is ask nicely and hope for the best.
If this is a regular problem, your best bet may be to add your partner and/or kid (if old enough) as an authorized user to a credit card so they get their own lounge pass. This is in my experience a very cost efficient to get lounge access: My partner and one of our kids are on my Chase Sapphire Preferred Card so they get Priority Pass for a fraction of what a regular membership would cost.
